# Rails 3 link_to routes (edit) nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-routes

Sorry if this has been asked elsewhere, but I can't figure this out. I have a forum with sections, topics, and replies. I'm trying to edit and delete replies from the show topic view. This is the structure:

```
resources :sections do
  resources :topics do
    resources :replies
  end
end
```

So I do a rake routes to see where I'm linking my edit reply. I see that its edit_section_topic_reply and in my link_to I add _path to it. Now this is what I can't figure out. What parameters am I passing it? Shouldn't it be:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_section_topic_reply_path(@reply, @topic, @section) %>
```

I get a `ActionController::RoutingError` in `Topics#show` when I do this.

```
No route matches {:topic_id=>#<Topic id: 2, section_id: 2, user_id: nil, subject: "subject", body: "body", created_at: "2011-03-04 08:37:37", updated_at: "2011-03-04 21:37:16">, :controller=>"replies", :action=>"edit", :section_id=>nil, :id=>#<Section id: 2, name: "Section", description: "Section Description", created_at: "2011-03-04 07:50:56", updated_at: "2011-03-04 07:50:56">}
```

It seems like it isn't passing IDs, but the nest before, my new topic works fine

```
new_section_topic_reply_path(@topic, @section)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I really dislike this aspect of the `link_to` helper. In the interest of making your code more readable and less prone to error, I would suggest that you be explicit about which IDs you are passing in.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_section_topic_reply_path(:id => @reply.id, 
                                                  :topic_id => @topic.id, 
                                                  :section_id => @section.id) %>
```

I've run into too many subtle and seemingly insane bugs due to params being out of order in a `link_to`.

Comment: Ah so in doing it this way, I realized the reply id wasn't calling it's specific ID. Really stupid mistake, I was in a loop, so of course @reply said nothing about which ID it actually was. <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_section_topic_reply_path(reply, @topic, @section) %> solved it the other way. reply.id this way. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, I had it backwards. it's (@section, @topic, path).

Comment: I think you meant (@section, @topic, @reply).

Answer (score 3):

One more way for edit link

```
<%= link_to [:edit,@section,@topic,@reply] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the right order should be:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_section_topic_reply_path(@section, @topic, @reply) %>
```