# routes not agreeing with show action (link)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple Model:  Practitioners have Appointments and Timecards (how much time was worked on a given day.

Practioners#show presents the practitioner and the associated Appointments/Timecards so I can Show them or Edit them (or add new ones).

View:

```
<% if @practitioner.timecard.count > 0 %>
  <p><strong>Time Card List</strong></p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Hours</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <% @practitioner.timecard.order("activity_date ASC").each do |t| %>
      <tr>
      <td><%= t.hours_worked %></td>
      <td><%= t.activity_date %></td>
      <td />
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_timecard_path([t.id]) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', timecard_path([t.id]) %></td>
    <% end %>
  </table>
<% else %>
  <p><strong>No Time Cards to display</strong></p>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "[Add Time Card]", new_practitioner_timecard_path(@practitioner) %>

<% if @practitioner.appointment.count > 0 %>
  <p><strong>Appointment List</strong></p>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>New?</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <% @practitioner.appointment.order("appointment_date ASC").each do |r| %>
      <tr>
      <td><%= r.patient.name %></td>
      <td><%= r.appointment_date %></td>
      <td><%= r.duration %> </td>
      <td><%= r.first_time %></td>
      <td />
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_appointment_path(r.id) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', appointment_path(r.id) %></td>
    <% end %>
  </table>
<% else %>  
  <p><strong>No Appointments to display</strong></p>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
  get "welcome/index"

  get "admin/index"

  resources :patients

   resources :locations, :shallow => true do
    resources :practitioners, :shallow => true do
      resources :timecards, :shallow => true 
      resources :appointments, :shallow => true
    end
  end
```

when I run rake routes, I clearly see

```
edit_appointment GET    /appointments/:id/edit(.:format)    appointments#edit
     appointment GET    /appointments/:id(.:format)         appointments#show
```

When I click the Edit or Show for timecards, it works fine.  When I click the edit or show for appointments, it errors:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"appointments", :id=>nil}
```

but I can see in my browser that the mouseover for an appointments Show link is:
localhost:3000/appointments/6

and for the Edit it gives
localhost:3000/appointments/6/edit

Why can't rails resolve this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is not in routing to your appointment controller for the initial request, but rather that when rendering the show/edit, your appointment controller/view is trying to create a link without passing a valid appointment. If I'm right, your stack trace will probably point to a `link_to`, `url_for`, or `appointment_path` call, but **in the context of having already started running your appointment controller**.

Another way to test this theory would be to clear out any logic in your `AppointmentController.show/edit` and also clear out its views.

Comment: It doesn't dump any stack/trace info... I just get the unhelpful suggestion to "run rake routes" for more info.

Comment: Ok. One quick thing to try would be to delete everything out of /views/appointments/show.html.erb and then visit /appointments/1 (or whatever).This error can be misleading because it can mean that the controller was found and run, but encountered an error creating links for the view.

Comment: I think you were ultimately right.  In both my Show and Edit I had links that used:
<%= link_to 'Show Appointment', appointment_path(@timecard) %> |
because I copied the navigation options from timecard (similar logic and relationships, right?)  @timecard was nil coming in, so I guess it was unable to render the appropriate html link - therefore it blew up.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this and see if anything changes in the console...

```
shallow do
  resources :locations do
    resources :practitioners do
      resources :timecards 
      resources :appointments
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Tried this as well.  But it gave me the same result.

Comment: But this is probably better syntax anyway, so I'll like it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help [Rails 3 link_to routes (edit) nested resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200574/rails-3-link-to-routes-edit-nested-resources)

Comment: That gave me the same result.

Comment: My mistake, I just updated my answer, take a look at that post, it may help